# Combine two complex SQL statements into one

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following 2 SQL statements:

```
Select count(project.id) as '# Projects', c2.name as ' Country name' from project, country c2, project_country where project_country.project_id = project.id and project_country.country_id= c2.id  group by c2.name;


select count(user.id)  as '# Consultants',c1.name as ' Country name'  from user,consultant_profile, country c1  where c1.id= user.country_id and user.is_active=1 and user.type=0 and user.id = consultant_profile.user_id group by country.name ;
```

Is it possible to combine the two queries based on the `country.id` field so I have only one result with #Projects, #Consultants and Country Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the `country` table on two aggregate queries on the other tables:

```
SELECT c.name AS country_name, num_projects, num_consultants
FROM   country c
JOIN   (SELECT   pc.country_id, COUNT(p.id) AS num_projects
        FROM     project p
        JOIN     project_country pc ON p.id = pc.projcet_id
        GROUP BY pc.country_id) x ON x.country_id = c.id
JOIN   (SELECT   u.country_id, COUNT(u.id) AS num_consultants
        FROM     user u
        WHERE    u.is_active = 1 AND u.type = 0
        GROUP BY u.country_id) y ON y.country_id = c.id
```